# Apache http request = python file execution? is this possible?

Tags: python, apache

I want to make a python script that executes if someone sends a request to my apache server. But i dont know if it is possible to execute a file by request.
The result should be a indicator if someone is entering my website, a led on a raspberry pi should turn on and after 500ms off.

So maybe someone can help me with this project.

Comment: You can create an API that will execute your python script.  This API will be called when someone sends a request to your apache server.

Comment: but do you have an idea how i can do that and this on the entire server

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can do this. It's probably easiest to use a simple web framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/), which can run under Apache using [mod_wsgi](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/mod_wsgi/).

You could also just [configure Apache to run Python scripts](https://www.linux.com/blog/configuring-apache2-run-python-scripts) directly, but you'll find using something like Flask makes things much easier.

Comment: And what does Flask in particular? Does it run under apache or does it make a new webserver?

Comment: Flask can run behind Apache, yes. 

Flask abstracts concepts like HTTP requests and responses for you, making it far easier to  write code which interacts with them.

Comment: The [Flask Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/) is excellent.

Comment: You said it wont be a webserver but it starts a webserver?

Comment: It has a built-in web server for development and testing purposes - very handy - but you wouldn't run it stand-alone in production. You'd use a WSGI server like gunicorn or tornado, or a server with a WSGI module like Apache or Nginx.